# which libraries do I need to run an HTTPS API on python?

Tags: python, api, compiler-errors

### I try to use some libraries including "https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/spot?currency=USD"
but i got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.240.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.240.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\Hessam\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.12.1559732655\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\__main__.py", line 45, in <module>
    cli.main()
  File "c:\Users\Hessam\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.12.1559732655\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 444, in main
    run()
  File "c:\Users\Hessam\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.12.1559732655\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 285, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target_as_str, run_name=compat.force_str("__main__"))
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.240.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 268, in run_path
    code, fname = _get_code_from_file(run_name, path_name)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.240.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 242, in _get_code_from_file
    code = compile(f.read(), fname, 'exec')
  File "c:\Users\Hessam\Python code\requests.py", line 3
    r = requests.get(https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts)
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

---

so please guide me on this
thanks in advance

Comment: You've missed quotes, it has to be `requests.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')`

Comment: time to delete the question